# What floor do Leonard, Sheldon and Penny live on?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

I know they live in apartments 4A and 4B, but in the episode "The Vegas Renormalization" (season 2 episode 21, episode 38 overall), when Sheldon and Penny walk up the stairs they only walk up three flights of stairs. So the question more is:

- are there other instances where characters are seen walking up four (or perhaps more) flights?
- have the creators/actors ever commented on this (it's really minor, so I would be a little surprised if they have)?
- is there anything else to say about this?
- can we actually tell if which floor is skipped in that sequence?

After two of the flights we can see the sign on 3A, so the missing floor most be either 1 or 2.
After the first flight the sign on the B apartment comes into view (but it's not readable to me), there's also a little white board with some text on that door, maybe we see that on other occasions that allow us to tell what floor that is?

And another related thing: Do we ever hear how many floors are in the building? The characters are seen on the roof (at least twice - for the expiriment with firing a laser at the moon, and for Howard and Bernadettes wedding) and the roof is referenced in "The Nerdvana Annihilation" (when then guys block the stairs moving the time machine up, and Penny has to go via the roof and the neighbor building to get to work). But I don't remember hearing how many floors are in the building.

Comment: I don't understand, if they walked up 3 flights they would be on the 4th floor. 1st flight takes you to 2nd floor, 2nd flight to 3rd floor, 3rd flight to 4th floor.

Comment: In the US, the ground floor **is** the first floor... so there are only three flights of stairs between the ground floor and the fourth floor. Are you assuming the European style of numbering where Ground floor is not the first floor?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware that it was done differently in the US.

Comment: It's not. It depends on the building. Some places number from the ground others from the second story.

Comment: @cde: That must cause confusion sometines.

Comment: Especially in elevators. Ground, landing, 1, star, 0, etc. But the 4th floor will always have the 4th apartments, even if it's the 4th or 5th story or the building.

Comment: In the US, the star is always the main entry floor regardless of what the number is. That's part of the ADA: "*In modern signage, at least in North America, a five-pointed star (★) additionally appears beside the button for the main entry floor. In the United States, the five-pointed star marking is mandated by Title III of the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA), as described in Section 4.10.12(2) of the ADA Accessibility Guidelines for Buildings and Facilities (ADAAG).*"

Comment: Which only applies to new constructions or any replacement elevator cabs. It doesn't apply to legacy or grandfathered buildings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the US, the ground floor is the first floor... so there are only three flights of stairs between the ground floor and the fourth floor.

There's no missing floor.